# How to center a Datamaps world map in two divs

Tags: html, css, datamaps

I am trying to center the world map in a full width and full height div but it keeps overflowing out of the div (view fiddle: http://jsbin.com/bifugahapa/edit?html,output)

Here is the code I am using to center the one div within another div to sort of draw it on a smaller div so even if it does overflow it won't produce scroll bars:

```
<div id="container1" style="
                           position: relative; 
                           width: 100%; 
                           height:95%; 
                           background-color: darkblue; 
                           padding-top: 40px">
     <div id="datamap" style="
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-height: 500px;
        height: 95%;
        width: 95%;
        background-color: black
        ">
     </div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to scale the world map or center the inner div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you can change your `display:table-cell` to `display: block` instead.

```
  #data-map {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 500px;
    height: 95%;
    width: 95%;
    background-color: black
  }
```

**Update:**

To center it also vertically you can use `position: absolute`

e.g.

```
  #data-map {
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
  }
```

[Working sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/9or0pZ8tappH3Up4c7Yo?p=preview)

**Update:**

Setting `height` `100%` needs your parent container a set height since you are using `%` but in that case the `body` you didn't set any height. So to fix that set `height: 100%` to `html` and `body` elements.

html, body {
  height: 100%
}

[Working code](http://plnkr.co/edit/W5ejxBaH7CjOzniXx96a?p=preview)

Comment: It is now centered horizontally but not vertically.

Comment: That is perfect. How do I make the outter div 100% in width and height? As soon as I change the height to any percentage it disappears.